# When re sizing web page, my html/css text moves to left side of the page

Tags: html, css, positioning, center

I am a noob when it comes to css, but I am experiencing a problem with my text in html/css.
When I re size my webpage my text goes to the left side of the page and gets messed up and out of place.
Here is my code:

```
**CSS:**
#NewsPosts {
position: fixed;
width: 75%;
top: 260px;
left: 32%;
padding: 30px;
overflow: hidden;

**HTML:**
<!--News Posts-->
            <div id="NewsPosts">
                <p>MY text goes here</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the outcome that you want to happen? IE, do you want `#NewPosts` to be centered on the page regardless of window size?

Comment: Yes that is what i want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center `#NewPosts` to all screens, you can accomplish that like this: 
**http://jsfiddle.net/uknqdr6g/**

**CSS**

```
#NewsPosts {
    width: 75%;
    /* margin-top:260px; If you want to use the margin-top */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

If you still want it to have a `position:fixed;` rearrange your code like this instead: **http://jsfiddle.net/uknqdr6g/1/**

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="NewsPosts">
        <p>MY text goes here</p>
        <img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-random-31108109-500-502.jpg" width="300" height="auto">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    left: 50%;
    width:400px;
    /* margin-top:260px; if you still want to use your margin-top */
    margin-left: -200px; /* Half of the width */
    background:#000;
    padding:20px;
    position: fixed;
}
#NewsPosts {
    width:100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for centering will bring up this simple idea:

html -

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Whatever we want to call this `div` but it is going to be whatever you want to be centered in the page. Then in the css, we have -

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

we put html and body at 100% so our container has something to go off and center off of.

```
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Is the important part. We are saying that `container` should be centered vertically on its parent's Y axis. The parents to `container` in this instance is `body` . And in order to get it centered on the x-axis, we put our friend

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x27u0e9y/)

Mess around with the `height` and `width` of each and see what happens. It should stay centered regardless of `container` `width` or `height`